# Why my GPU rendering time is more than CPU rendering time?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have recently installed Nvidea geForce GT610 graphic card (CUDA enabled) to enhance the rendering time for a simple scene under cycles. To my surprise I found the rendering time with GPU setting is much longer (more than 2 time) than with CPU setting.  Searching the net could not provide any solution.  Can someone exlain me why this is so?

Comment: What are your tile settings?

Comment: It looks like [your GPU has only 48 CUDA cores](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-610/specifications), which, if I'm not missing anything, just doesn't sound like enough.

Comment: I had the same problem. Changing the tile size to 256x256 fixed it for me.

Comment: I would recommend increasing the tile size.

Comment: Are you sure your GPU is receiving the 300W it needs? I had the same problem with mine...

Comment: I used the tile size 256X256 (even tried 512X512)and set the No of bounces to the minimum.  Still I am getting the same result.